# Get library name from keyword - robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have used the below document to get the list of keywords that are used in a .robot file.
https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/autodoc/robot.parsing.html#parsing-data-to-tokens

Basically after the file is tokenized, all the tokens with type "KEYWORD" are keywords used in the robot file.
I want to find out to which library a keyword belongs to. For example, if there is a keyword "Open Browser" or "Click Element", I want to get the name of the library (in this case, they belong to Selenium Library).

Is there any package available that outputs the libraray name based on the keyword?